# How to pass the output of a command as a variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to pass the output of an awk command as a variable in a bash script, but not having much success so any help is appreciated.

```
homedirectory=$(awk /stephen/ /etc/passwd | awk -F/home/ '{print $2}' | awk -F/downloads '{print $1}')

echo '$homedirectory'
```

I want to extract the home directory of user stephen from the /etc/passwd, so the result I want is 0001

```
/etc/passwd

statd:x:102:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false

bind:x:103:106::/var/cache/bind:/bin/false

sshd:x:104:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin

mysql:x:105:107:MySQL Server,,,:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/false

messagebus:x:106:108::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false

stephen:x:1039:1031::/home/0001/downloads:/bin/false
```

Comment: Do you really need 3 separate awk invocations there?  What exactly are you trying to do?  It sure looks like you are trying to make things far more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: You'd be better off explaining what you're trying to actually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't look at `/etc/passwd`. `echo ~username`, in your case `echo ~stephen` will do what you want.

From your `/etc/passwd` result would be

```
$ echo ~stephen
/home/0001
$ basename `echo ~stephen`
0001
```

Edit: This was before the edit applied proper formatting to your `/etc/passwd` contents. I didn't catch the homedir was `/home/0001/downloads`. What you're asking for is something that will not always have a consistent result unless you always expect to have the inspected user's homedir be in `/home`. There are a million ways to do this, most which will be somewhat wrong, until you provide information on your expected constraints.

In any case, apply your filtering to the output of `echo ~username`. You could use a variety of utilities after that, like `basename`, `awk`, `sed`, `cut`, etc.

Comment: +1, this is a far more appropriate approach and it should work on all POSIX systems, including Macs (which use `etc/passwd` only in single-user mode).

Comment: The result of basename `echo ~stephen` is downloads. I could use this I suppose echo ~stephen | awk -F/home/ '{print $2}' | awk -F/downloads '{print $1}' but I am still stuck with how to use the output as a variable. Actually that works, thanks

Comment: Actually, using backticks is pretty 1995 at this point. I'd suggest trying the $(/usr/bin/foo argv) syntax first, as it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Scrap what you have and use:

```
getent passwd stephen | cut -d: -f6
```

Or even

```
cd ~stephen && pwd
```

Comment: Not every Unix system has the `getent` command. It would make more sense to use what is universally available.

Answer (score 1):

Your three awks worked (although as others have said, it could have been done a lot better).

The final problem was that `echo '$homedirectory'` should have been `echo "$homedirectory"` since the shell looks inside double quotes but not single quotes.